# Remove item from array using jQuery button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list,
which has an image, and an 'x' image (Close.gif)
I am not sure how to make the ListItem be removed when the 'x' image is clicked.

```
<ul id="cardList" class="cardList">    
    <li id="1" class="ui-state-default" data-type="cover" onclick="onClickCard(this)">
    Cover 00 
    <img src="./Close.gif" alt="" onclick="onClickClose(this)"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I only know how to have the image removed when the 'x' mark is clicked.

```
var onClickCard = function(asd){
    $(asd).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your `onClickCard` function is used to remove list items when you click on the list item itself and the function you want to handle here is `onClickClose`

After that, to solve your problem you can use **[.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)** or **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** to remove parent `li` of clicked image:

```
var onClickClose = function(asd){
    $(asd).parent().remove(); // or .closest('li').remove()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you've got the name of the function wrong if you want it to fire when you click the image.

Change your function to this...

```
var onClickClose = function(asd){
    $(asd).closest("li").remove();
}
```

Comment: It's not wrong, the `onClickCard` is for `li` element

Comment: But he wants it to fire when he clicks the image, not the li ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
var onClickClose= function(asd){
    $(asd).closest("li").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var onClickClose = function(asd){
   $(asd).closest('li').remove();
}
```